# How to write following method in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
     reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
            delegate:(id<CallOutAnnotationViewDelegate>)delegate;
```

above is Objective C Code, how to write with swift?

Comment: That's not really code. That's a method declaration.

Comment: yes,but in swift ,how to write??

Comment: Please read the Swift book or find some Swift tutorials before posting such a basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :
//Define your function like this

```
func initWithAnnotation(annotation:MKAnnotation, reuseIdentifier:String, completion: ()->Void) {
          //Your implementation goes here

         //for call back
         completion()
    }
```

//call above function by this:

```
 self.initWithAnnotation(Your_MKProtocol, reuseIdentifier: "identifier", completion: {
                  //Your call back implementations
                 //Similar to delegate callback
       })
```